# Does a normal Windows Installation include the MFC100.dll?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mfc

Easy Question, but can't google the answer.

Does a normal Windows Installation include the MFC100.dll libary?
If so, since when does the MFC100.dll come with the windows installation and not from a VC+ Redist 2010? And why isn't Windows 10 already including the newer version of the MFc (MFC120.dll)

Path for the MFC DLL File is Windows(SYSWOW64)\mfc100.dll

Sorry for my horrible english, i'm not a native speaker.

Comment: My Windows for Workgroups 3.11 does not contain this dll, I checked only seconds ago. Which Windows versions are you interested in ?

Comment: actually the differences since windows 7 and since when the file is included
btw. which mfc file do u have? mfc90?

Comment: There are two important questions here. _Since when_ does Windows include MFC100.dll, and equally important, _until when ?_ Unfortunately the answer to the second question requires a crystal ball.

Comment: [Windows is not an MFC delivery channel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/11/7065021.aspx) and [Windows is not a Microsoft Visual C/C++ Run-Time delivery channel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't rely on any MFC DLL being installed on any Windows.

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235264(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If you dynamically link your application to the MFC library, you have to redistribute Msvcr100.dll because all MFC DLLs use the shared version of the C run-time library (CRT). You also have to redistribute Mfc100u.dll or Mfc100.dll.

[MSDN blog says](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/11/7065021.aspx):

> Windows is not an MFC delivery channel

There is no if or when. You need the MFC DLL? Then you must install it. And take care to install the version you linked against (might change with a Visual Studio service pack).

Comment: that actually answers my question, so windows delivering the mfc files is just a bonus

Comment: Just to provide a concrete data point, I've identified two machines of mine, one running Windows 7 and one Windows 8.1, *neither* of which have mfc100.dll.  It really *isn't* included in Windows - but *is* included in a lot of other software, both Microsoft and third-party, which may well have been pre-installed on your particular machine.